# How to detect if current_setting is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I’m writing a function which gets if the current user has “starred” a row. The current user’s id is stored in a local variable and accessible through the postgresql `current_setting` function. How do I provide a default value for `current_setting`? Here is my function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION current_user_starred(star_group_id integer)
  RETURNS boolean
  AS $$
    SELECT COUNT(*) != 0
      FROM star
     WHERE star_group_id = star_group_id
       AND starrer_id = current_setting('user_id')::integer;
  $$
  LANGUAGE sql;
```

For a default setting I would like to use -1 or 0 for `current_setting('user_id')`.

Comment: Use a dot-qualified parameter like `myapp.user_id` and set a default with `alter user ... set ....` or `alter database ... set ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what @Craig commented: set a [customized option](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-custom.html) for role or database:

```
ALTER ROLE SET foo.user_id = '-1';
```

Or:

```
ALTER DATABASE SET foo.user_id = '-1';
```

Or add the setting to `postgresql.conf` (for the whole DB cluster) and reload.

Else you can trigger an exception if the parameter has not been set, yet:

> ```
> ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "foo.user_id"
> SQL state: 42704
> ```

You also need a working function. What you presented is broken.

```
CREATE FUNCTION current_user_starred(_star_group_id integer)
  RETURNS boolean AS
$func$
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   star s, (SELECT current_setting('foo.user_id') AS _user_id) x
   WHERE  s.star_group_id = _star_group_id
   AND    s.starrer_id = CASE x._user_id WHEN '' THEN -1 ELSE x._user_id::integer END
   );
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

- Avoid naming conflicts by table-qualifying columns and / or using non-conflicting parameter names. I did both.
- Use a `CASE` statement to default to `-1` or whatever when the parameter hast been reset to `''` (empty string).
- `EXISTS` can be substantially cheaper than `COUNT(*) != 0` for your purpose.
- I retrieve the parameter value in a tiny subselect in the `FROM` list. Simplifies the `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this:

```
select coalesce( nullif(current_setting( 'my.var', true ),'')::timestamptz, now() )
```

In this example if 'my.var' is not defined `current_setting` will return empty string and then `nullif` will return NULL.

`coalesce` function will return first not null argument, `now()` at this case.
Instead of `now()` you can use any value, which will be used as default.